# What will happen if the variance of Gaussian kernel in Gaussian kernel SVM decreases?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, svm, overfitting

I prepare my self for ML exam ad I saw this question.
[image]

My note tells me that the option (3) is correct, but maybe there is a trick because all of sentences look like true. (it means all of them seem correct). what is wrong in my understanding?

Comment: There are different interpretations of $C$ in SVM, can you please explain it?

Comment: @gunes C is a regularization parameter. (min |w|^2+C∑ξ.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think #1 is true because if you decrease C, then you are allowing more misclassification in the training set. So it can't mean more overfitting.

I think #2 is partly true, but how can you ever for sure know what will happen in the testing set? I find this strange. Certainly in the training set, as you increase C, you will decrease the number of misclassified data in the training set. But how can you ever guarantee that your number of correctly classified testing points would increase. If that were true then everybody would just have an extra high C value. So I don't know, I wouldn't even say that's correct.

#3 I think is true. The width of the gaussian kernel itself will be smaller, therefore being more likely to fit to the training set but not generalizing well with the test set. (see here: http://haohanw.blogspot.com/2014/03/ml-how-sigma-matters-in-svm-rbf-kernel.html)

#4 Again, how can you know what happens in the test set. If you knew a solid rule like this, then no one would need grid searches. Anything could happen if you increase the width of the kernel. It could either increase the number of correctly-classified points, or impinge on the boundary of the other class, causing a higher error rate.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. we don't know anything about test but how we say overfittng happens? overfitting is related to test error too.
about #4 we we increase variance, the decision boundary will be smoother. so we can say what will happen for taring data but we cant decide about test data?

Comment: Your first question is a good question. As the model function becomes more and more complex, overfitting is more likely to occur. I urge you to look at this link I sent for #3: http://haohanw.blogspot.com/2014/03/ml-how-sigma-matters-in-svm-rbf-kernel.html. There, you can see an image of a Gaussian kernel fit to some training data. At the highest level of overfitting, you won't even see a green boundary area. The boundary will literally be so small that it encompasses only the points from a single class. In the training set, that will give you 100% accuracy. Without even seeing the test set,

Comment: we know that the model has overfit. This is one example of how we can know the model is overfitting without a test set.

Comment: Yes for #4, a larger sigma might indicate a larger area of the class boundary for a single class compared with with a smaller sigma. A larger boundary can mean that either: 1) the model overfits less to the training set and is more generalizable to the test data, or 2) the class boundary area is so big now that it misclassifies points from the other class much more often. Therefore, we cannot guess the result of the error rate. There is always a "sweet spot" of the ideal sigma value in SVM that can only be determined through a grid search. It is a value which is not too high or too low.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comments. What does this sentence mean? "the gamma parameter defines how far the influence of a single training example reaches, with low values meaning ‘far’ and high values meaning ‘close’"

Comment: As you said, we don't say what will happen for test data. Is it true for validation set too?

Comment: The sentence means that the classification boundary will be larger as gamma is smaller and the boundary will be smaller as gamma is larger. This is the opposite of what happens when you increase or decrease sigma because gamma = 1/(2*sigma^2).

Comment: For your second question, this depends on where the validation data comes from. If you are doing a k-fold cross validation, the average behavior of your validation data might match the training results much better than a test set. The validation set often comes from a subset of the training set, so this set comes from a much more similar distribution than the test set might (the test set can even be from a totally different dataset). So, in principle, yes we can say that the validation set is also unpredictable, but it's going to be "more predictable" than the test set, if that makes sense.